# ListObject sorting corruption

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba class that I am using to manage different views of the same ListObject (ie, filtering & sorting), and am getting some corruption that seems to be tied to the sorting. It seems easy enough for Excel to repair with the following logged error:

```
...Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been 
repaired or discarded.</info></additionalInfo><removedRecords summary="Following is a list of 
removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/tables/table1.xml 
part (Table)</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

Can anyone see what the problem might be from this error? (I can post the code I am using if need be)

Comment: You need to post the code, please. There's no useful information in the repair logs generally.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/naughty-sorts/

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers; that was *exactly* the problem (duplicated sort range key left over from a cut and paste). If you want to turn that into an answer we I can give it to you and close this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your sort fields are referencing the correct ranges, as in the code below copied from [colinlegg.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/naughty-sorts](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/naughty-sorts/).

```
With wksTarget.Sort

    With .SortFields

        .Clear

        .Add _
            Key:=wksTarget.Range("A2:A6"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Add _
            Key:=wksTarget.Range("B2:B6"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Add _
            Key:=wksTarget.Range("C2:C6"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    End With

    .SetRange wksTarget.Range("A1:C6")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Sometimes you copy and paste code when adding new sort fields and then forget to update the range for the Key property.